# PHP dynamic HTML to PDF certificate with mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Looking for a way to output PHP dynamic html into a certificate looking document that is PDF - I have the html with certificate looking fine, but when i use mPDF to return the html results to a PDF, I get nothing. i'm sure it's the way the html is stored in the php var and the scripts need to be outside the html, but i'm not sure how to accomplish this?

```
<?php

$html = '
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<TITLE>Certificate</TITLE>

<SCRIPT>
var strTitle = "MIEMSS Course Title";

var g_arrMonths = new Array()

// Enter the month names below
try
{
g_arrMonths[0] = __MONTH_JAN__; 
g_arrMonths[1] = __MONTH_FEB__;
g_arrMonths[2] = __MONTH_MAR__;
g_arrMonths[3] = __MONTH_APR__;
g_arrMonths[4] = __MONTH_MAY__;
g_arrMonths[5] = __MONTH_JUN__;
g_arrMonths[6] = __MONTH_JUL__;
g_arrMonths[7] = __MONTH_AUG__;
g_arrMonths[8] = __MONTH_SEP__;
g_arrMonths[9] = __MONTH_OCT__;
g_arrMonths[10] = __MONTH_NOV__;
g_arrMonths[11] = __MONTH_DEC__;

// Enter the column headers
var g_strDateTime       = __DATE_TIME__;
var g_strStudentScore   = __STUDENT_SCORE__;
var g_strPassingScore   = __PASSING_SCORE__;
var g_strResult1        = __RESULT__;
var g_strQuestion       = __QUESTION__;
var g_strCorrectAns     = __CORRECT_ANS__;
var g_strResult2        = __RESULT__;
var g_strStudentAns     = __STUDENT_ANS__;
var g_strPointsAwarded  = __POINTS_AWARD__;
var g_strNeutral        = __NEUTRAL__;
var g_strCorrect        = __CORRECT__;
var g_strIncorrect      = __INCORRECT__;
}
catch(e)
{
g_arrMonths[0] = "January"; 
g_arrMonths[1] = "February";
g_arrMonths[2] = "March";
g_arrMonths[3] = "April";
g_arrMonths[4] = "May";
g_arrMonths[5] = "June";
g_arrMonths[6] = "July";
g_arrMonths[7] = "August";
g_arrMonths[8] = "September";
g_arrMonths[9] = "October";
g_arrMonths[10] = "November";
g_arrMonths[11] = "December";

// Enter the column headers
var g_strDateTime = "Date / Time";
var g_strStudentScore = "Student Score";
var g_strPassingScore = "Passing Score";
var g_strResult1 = "Result";
var g_strQuestion = "Question";
var g_strCorrectAns = "Correct Answer";
var g_strResult2 = "Result";
var g_strStudentAns = "Student Answer";
var g_strPointsAwarded = "Points Awarded";
var g_strNeutral = "Neutral";
var g_strCorrect = "Correct";
var g_strIncorrect = "Incorrect";
}

</SCRIPT>

<STYLE>

TD {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
width: 12.5%;
}

.CORRECT {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
color: #008800;
}

.INCORRECT {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
color: #880000;
}

.NEUTRAL {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
color: #000088;
}

.QUESTION {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: left;
width: 46.25%;  
}

.NUMBER {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
width: 3.75%;
}

.DATE {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;

}

.DATETIME {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.SUMMARY {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
}

H1 {
font-size:14pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
}

TH {
font-size:12pt;
font-family:arial;
}

.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

H2 {
font-size:14pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
position: absolute; 
top: 200px; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
}

</STYLE>

<SCRIPT>
var g_oContentResults = window.opener.g_oContentResults;
var g_listQuizzes = window.opener.g_listQuizzes;
var g_oPrintOptions = window.opener.g_oPrintOptions;

var player = GetPlayer()
    //var myscore = player.GetVar("g_strStudentScore");
var scoreTotal = player.GetVar("userScore").toString();

function FormatDate(dtmDate)
{
var strResult = "";
var nHours = dtmDate.getHours();
var strAM = "am";
var nMinutes = dtmDate.getMinutes();
var strMinutes = "" + nMinutes;

if (nMinutes < 10)
{
    strMinutes = "0" + nMinutes;
}

if (nHours == 12)
{
    strAM = "pm";
}

if (nHours > 12)
{
    nHours -= 12;
    strAM = "pm";
}


strResult += "<P>"
strResult += g_arrMonths[dtmDate.getMonth()] + " ";
strResult += dtmDate.getDate() + ", ";
strResult += dtmDate.getFullYear() + "  ";
strResult += nHours + ":";
strResult += strMinutes + " ";
strResult += strAM;
strResult += "</P>"
return strResult;
}

</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<img src="quizimages/cert.png">
</center>
<p>
<SCRIPT>

//document.write("<P><H1>" + strTitle + "</H1></P>");

if (g_oPrintOptions.strName)
{
if (g_oPrintOptions.strName.length > 0)
{
    document.write("<H2><CENTER><I>This certifies:</I></br></br>");
    document.write("" + g_oPrintOptions.strName + "</br></br>");
    document.write("<I>has completed the course:</I></br></br>");
    document.write("" + strTitle + "</br></br>");
    document.write("</br></br>");
    document.write( FormatDate(g_oContentResults.dtmFinished));
    document.write("Score: " + g_listQuizzes[g_oPrintOptions.strMainQuizId].nPtScore + "</br></br></H2>" );     
    document.write('<center> <input type=button onClick="window.print()" value="Print This Page"/> </center>');
}
}


    document.write("USER SCORE: "+scoreTotal+""); 

    document.write("<H2><CENTER><I>This certifies:</I></br></br>");
    document.write("" + g_oContentResults.strName + "</br></br>");
    document.write("<I>has completed the course:</I></br></br>");
    document.write("" + strTitle + "</br></br>");
    document.write("</br></br>");
    document.write( FormatDate(g_oContentResults.dtmFinished));
    document.write("Score: " + g_listQuizzes[g_oContentResults.strMainQuizId].nPtScore + "</br></br></H2>" );       
    document.write('<center> <input type=button onClick="window.print()" value="Print This Page"/> </center>');


</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
';


//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================

include("../mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;

//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript variables in the html load after the php page is drawn. The javascript var needs to be passed to php var via a POST, GET, or query string and picked up in a refresh or new page - the $html thus needs to be just that html and not contain script.